# Search and replace in VIM only on specific places

Tags: vim

I have a `.json` file and I want to search and replace `}` with `},`. However, I want to apply this only in the case where I have the text `"item_secret": "98ax3fsrv"}`. The string `98ax3fsrv` will differ both in length and content. So I am actually looking for something like `"item_secret": "%s"}` and replace it with `"item_secret": "%s"},`.

Is there any way to apply this search and replace after which combination of strings?

Answer (score 4):

Two different ways come to mind:

1.

```
:%s/"item_secret": ".*"}/&,
```

Just a straightforward search and replace. In this, the `&` represents the entire string that `"item_secret": ".*"` matched. If there might be more quotes on the line after `"98ax3fsrv"`, you might need either

```
:%s/"item_secret": "[^"]*"}/&,
```

or

```
:%s/"item_secret": ".\{-}"}/&,
```

2.

```
:g/item_secret/norm A,
```

I like this way more. It says "on every line matching `item_secret`, run the command `normal A,`", which enters insert mode at the end of the line and appends a comma. This will only work if `}` is the end of the line everywhere `item_secret` appears.

Comment: 3. `:g/{pattern}/s/$/,` to replace all *end of lines* that contains `{pattern}` with a comma. It *may* be faster than executing `A,` if you have *alot* of substitutions to make.